# Does grpc.Dial() create a http/2 connection?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am a bit confused about grpc and http/2. From what I learned, grpc is a RPC framework and can use different types of transports and http/2 is just one of the transports.

In golang, `grpc.Dial()` will create a connection to the server and the grpc server is created by `grpc#Server.Serve()`. So what is this connection? Is that a http/2 connection?

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to a server with gRPC, that does establish a single HTTP/2 connection that can be shared between many gRPC requests (the channel concept).

gRPC is indeed an RPC framework, built on HTTP/2. By default, it uses Protobufs as the serialization protocol, but that can be customised.

Think of gRPC as an RPC application layer over HTTP/2. To quote the [FAQ](https://grpc.io/faq/):
"... gRPC is also a set of libraries that will provide higher-level features consistently across platforms that common HTTP libraries typically do not. Examples of such features include:

interaction with flow-control at the application layer
cascading call-cancellation
load balancing & failover
"